# Issue in design replication

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the design attached using HTML and CSS but rather the design is coming out awkwardly. I have attached both the designs which I am trying to replicate and what I got as a result. Please let me alternate solutions for the problem.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="item-list">
  <div class="item item1">
    <table cellspacing="50">
      <tr>
        <td class="col1"><img src="" alt=""></td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <h3> Photosnap </h3>
              New!
              Featured
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <h2> Senior Frontend Developer </h2>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <p>1d ago . Full Time . USA only</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <div class="categories">
            <!-- Item Start -->
            <table>
              <tr>
                <!-- Role -->
                <td><p>Frontend</p></td>
                <!-- Level -->
                <td><p>Senior</p></td>
                <!-- Languages -->
                <td><p>HTML</p></td>
                <td><p>CSS</p></td>
                <td><p>JavaScript</p></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <!-- Item End -->
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.categories p {
    color: hsl(180, 29%, 50%);
    font-weight: 550;
    background-color: hsl(180, 31%, 95%);
    padding: 10%;
    margin: 7%;
}
```

Comment: There is no design attached, as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry ... Link to my design is https://ibb.co/ssJDLbb

Comment: Could you please describe problem?

Comment: Re edit - embedded screenshot from link

Comment: @Alex I was not able to replicate the design .. The code is attached but I forgot to attach the design and the problem. Please look into this link You will get my problem . https://ibb.co/ssJDLbb

Answer (score 1):

With `margin` and `padding` it's a good idea to use absolute values instead of relative ones:

```css
.categories p {
  color: hsl(180, 29%, 50%);
  font-weight: 550;
  background-color: hsl(180, 31%, 95%);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <div class="item item1">
    <table cellspacing="50">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="categories">
            <!-- Item Start -->
            <table>
              <tr>
                <!-- Role -->
                <td>
                  <p>Frontend</p>
                </td>
                <!-- Level -->
                <td>
                  <p>Senior</p>
                </td>
                <!-- Languages -->
                <td>
                  <p>HTML</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>CSS</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>JavaScript</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Item End -->
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Though, I would suggest not using an entire table element just for a few `p` tags:

```css
.categories p {
  color: hsl(180, 29%, 50%);
  font-weight: 550;
  background-color: hsl(180, 31%, 95%);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.categories {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
  <div class="item item1">
    <table cellspacing="50">
      <tr>
        <td class="categories">
          <!-- Item Start -->
          <!-- Role -->
          <p>Frontend</p>
          <!-- Level -->
          <p>Senior</p>
          <!-- Languages -->
          <p>HTML</p>
          <p>CSS</p>
          <p>JavaScript</p>
          <!-- Item End -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thanks for your efforts. I will go through the alternate solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

With margin and padding it's a good idea to use absolute values instead of relative ones: